# Create a pivot dataframe of occurrence based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame named check-ins that shows that a user visited a venue. I want to create a data frame that shows that these two users visited N numbers of venues together (to show that their taste is similar)

check-ins dataframe has two column: user_id and venue_id

I thought I can create all combinations of users that checked in a each venue and count the number of time it happened by this:

```
all_combinations = []
for venue in tqdm(venue_list):
    vals = checkins_2[checkins_2['venue_id'] == venue]
    if vals.shape[0] > 1:
        [all_combinations.append(item) for item in list(itertools.combinations(vals.user_id.unique(), 2))]
```

and then create a data set with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_combinations)
df.columns = ['first_','second_']
bigs = []
smalls = []
lens = []
for row in tqdm(df.itertuples(), total=df.shape[0]):
    ins = df.loc[((df.first_ == row.first_) & (df.second_ == row.second_)) | ((df.first_ == row.second_) & (df.second_ == row.first_))]
    len_ = len(ins)
    big = max(ins.iloc[0].values)
    small = min(ins.iloc[0].values)
    lens.append(len_)
    smalls.append(small)
    bigs.append(big)
```

However, this code is not efficient at all! and it takes 100 hour to run even for a small subset.

How can I achieve this with a more efficient *python way*?

Comment: Can you share a sample what you have in data frame and what you need as result?

Answer (score 1):

I created a data frame with Users and Venues.  Then using the logical `and` operator shows common venues, and `sum` shows number of common venues.  First, create sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
headers = ('venue_id', 'user_id', 'visited')
check_in = [
    (10, 1, True), (10, 2, True), (10, 3, True), 
    (11, 2, True), (11, 3, True), (11, 4, True), 
    (12, 3, True), (12, 4, True), (12, 5, True)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = check_in, columns = headers)
df = df.pivot(index = 'venue_id', columns = 'user_id', values = 'visited')
df = df.fillna(False)
print(df)

user_id       1      2     3      4      5
venue_id                                  
10         True   True  True  False  False
11        False   True  True   True  False
12        False  False  True   True   True
```

Sample result: show venues visited by '2' and '3'

```
df[2] & df[3]  # what did `2` and `3` both visit?

venue_id
10     True
11     True
12    False
dtype: bool
```

Finally, apply `and` to all pairs of Users (columns).  The resulting matrix is symmetric, so you could adjust the inner loop to exploit this.

```
records = [
    (user1, user2, (df[user1] & df[user2]).sum())
    for user1 in df.columns
    for user2 in df.columns
]
records = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ('user1', 'user2', 'count'))
records = records.pivot(index = 'user1', columns = 'user2', values = 'count')
records

user2  1  2  3  4  5
user1               
1      1  1  1  0  0
2      1  2  2  1  0
3      1  2  3  2  1
4      0  1  2  2  1
5      0  0  1  1  1
```